# Как достать список аудиозаписей VK, используя ключ доступа пользователя, python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Надо вытащить список аудиозаписей из вк, используя ключ доступа пользователя. Нужны только названия треков и их авторы.

Comment: По-моему, это API прикрыли для обычных людей. Читал ранее, что только некоторые мобильные приложения могут аудиозаписи получить через API и люди взламывали приложения (или снифали трафик), чтобы получить TOKEN. Если не через API работать, то можно сделать парсер (requests+bs4 или selenium) и им вытащить